# Confused about encoding issue when read from mysql via python code

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

There is one row in Mysql table as following:

```
1000, Intel® Rapid Storage Technology
```

The table's charset='utf8' when was created.
When I used python code to read it, it become the following:

```
IntelÂ® Management Engine Firmware
```

My python code as following:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(db,user,passwd,dbName,port,charset='utf8')
```

The weird thing was that when I removed the charset='utf8' as following: 
`db = MySQLdb.connect(db,user,passwd,dbName,port)`, the result become correct.

Why when I indicated charset='utf8' in my code, but got wrong result please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving off the charset in the connect string and then setting afterwards?

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(db,user,passwd,dbName,port)
db.set_character_set('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.
This discussion also applies to **Double Encoding**, which is not necessarily visible.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `&lt;meta charset=UTF-8>`.

See also [Python notes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)